# non-ASCII character declaration

Tags: c, character, special-characters

I would like to store a character (in order to compare it with other characters).

If I declare the variable like this :

```
char c = 'é';
```

everything works well, but I get these warnings :

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   char c = 'é';
            ^
ii.c:12:3: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
   char c = 'é';
```

I think I understand why there is these warnings, but I wonder why does it still work?
And should I define it like this : `int d = 'é';` although it takes more space in memory?
Moreover, I also get the warning below with this declaration :

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

int d = 'é';

Do I miss something? Thanks ;)

Comment: In which way does it work? Does `'é'` compare equal to e.g. 169 (which isn't what you want, I guess)?

Comment: This way :   `char d = 'é';
  char *w = "aaéaéaa";
  while (*w++){if (d == *w) printf ("ok\n");}`
prints ok ok

Comment: On my platform, this gives the same output with `char *w = "aa\xa9" "aéaa";` (0xA9 is 169, which is not the utf-8 encoding of `é`). In other words: If some byte and `'é'` compare unequal, then they are certainly not the same, but not the other way round. And what you do has no portably reproducible results: The value of a character constant with more than one character given is _implementation-defined_.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarifications, but what's the good way to do this for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`é` has the Unicode code point 0xE9, the UTF-8 encoding is `"\xc3\xa9"`.

I assume your source file is encoded in UTF-8, so

```
char c = 'é';
```

is (roughly) equivalent to

```
char c = '\xc3\xa9';
```

How such character constants are treated is implementation-defined. [For GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html):

> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final bit-pattern is given type int, and is therefore signed, regardless of whether single characters are signed or not (a slight change from versions 3.1 and earlier of GCC). If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target int the compiler issues a warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored.
>
> For example, 'ab' for a target with an 8-bit char would be interpreted as `(int) ((unsigned char) 'a' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'b')`, and `'\234a'` as `(int) ((unsigned char) '\234' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'a')`.

Hence, `'é'` has the value 0xC3A9, which fits into an `int` (at least for 32-bit `int`), but not into an (8-bit) `char`, so the conversion to `char` is again [implementation-defined](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2<sup>N</sup> to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

This gives (with signed `char`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("%d %d\n", 'é', (char)'é');
    if((char)'é' == (char)'©') puts("(char)'é' == (char)'©'");
}
```

*Output:*

```
50089 -87
(char)'é' == (char)'©'
```

50089 is 0xC3A9, 87 is 0xA9.

So you lose information when storing `é` into a `char` (there are characters like `©` which compare equal to `é`). You can

1. Use `wchar_t`, an implementation-dependent wide character type which is 4 byte on Linux holding UTF-32: `wchar_t c = L'é';`. You can convert them to the locale-specific multibyte-encoding (probably UTF-8, but you'll need to set the locale before, see `setlocale`; note, that changing the locale may change the behaviour of functions like `isalpha` or `printf`) by `wcrtomb` or use them directly and also use wide strings (use the `L` prefix to get wide character string literals)
2. Use a string and store UTF-8 in it (as in `const char *c = "é";` or `const char *c = "\u00e9";` or `const char *c = "\xc3\xa9;"`, with possibly different semantics; for C11, perhaps also look for *UTF-8 string literals* and the `u8` prefix)

Note, that file streams have an *orientation* (cf. `fwide`).

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Try using `wchar_t` rather than `char`.  `char` is a single byte, which is appropriate for ASCII but not for multi-byte character sets such as UTF-8.  Also, flag your character literal as being a wide character rather than a narrow character:

```
#include <wchar.h>
...
wchar_t c = L'é';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried to flag the character but after the comparison with an other character that I get further with `*string ` doesn't work. Using `wchar_t` doesn't change nothing. And I still don't know why it still works with my declaration although there should not be enough place in the memory for an extended character ;)

Comment: How is "string" declared?

Comment: `char d = 'é'; char *w = "aaéaéaa"; while (*w++){if (d == *w) printf ("ok\n");}`

Comment: Using a narrow character, a narrow character pointer, a narrow character literal, and a narrow character string literal won't work with wide character data.  Use this instead: `wchar_t d = L'é'; wchar_t *w = L"aaéaéaa"; while (*w++){if (d == *w) printf ("ok\n");}`

Comment: Yep but the problem is that in the real program I get the string like this ` wchar_t *word = strtok(line, "\t");` 
How should I place the flag?

Comment: `strtok` is for narrow-character strings.  Try using `wcstok`.  You can't mix narrow-character and wide-character stuff like this and expect it to work.

Comment: I also use fgets before strtok... Is there also an other function to use instead?

Comment: Use `fgetws` for wide characters.  There's always a "w" somewhere in the names of wide-character functions.  Unfortunately, it's not always in the same place.

Comment: I should maybe open a new topic, but fgetws(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, F)` returns NULL after the first special character found in the file...